# Sharepoint newbie: How to create time entry dashboard?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

My boss has asked me to look into setting up a copy of sharepoint on our server and creating a dashboard that allows employees to view their tasks, punch in/out, etc.

At this point, I have VERY little experience with sharepoint.  I've seen sharepoint tutorials that seem to be simple non-coding setups & I've seen some that involve creating sharepoint pages from code.  What's the best approach for creating this time entry page?  Is there something already built that I can just plug in and modify or is it best to code it from scratch?  Just looking for some good starting points.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't code from scratch, you could find a site template (.stp) somewhere which is free or costs 50 CUR and which you can install in your SharePoint server and modify further to your liking.

For example see whether "Case Management" below satisfies more than half of your (boss) requirements or not: http://sp2010teamplates.codeplex.com/ If not, Google for more.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @RoManiac. Don't get to code from scratch.

As an alternate, SharePoint is a great platform for quickly creating data entry / manage data apps like the one you mentioned using "Lists".

Consider every SharePoint list as a "Virtual table" in an SQL Server with CRUD screens getting auto generated. That means that if you create a list (table) called "TimeSheetEntry" with fields (Columns) called Project Name (Text), Project Task (Text), DateWorked (DateTime), HoursWorked (Integer), SharePoint will automatically generate Data entry screens for this list. You can expose this list to your end users and they can start entering their time sheets. CreatedBy field is an automatic field that should track who entered the data.

You can create views (Like SQL views) that allow users to see only their time records.

Hope that answers

Cheers
VJ